# Not able to reconnect to RTMP stream after lost connection

Tags: streaming, rtmp, flowplayer

I am using Flowplayer for   RTMP streaming of a VOD application. I need the user to be able to resume the playback from the same point in case of reconnection after a momentary failure in internet connection. Is this possible with Flowplayer. I have successfully implemented the Flowplayer RTMP streaming.

I noticed a `canDispatchStreamNotFound()` method in the `NetStreamControllingStreamProvider` class.

Can this method in anyway be used to detect that connection is not available anymore and resume playback when connection comes.  I tried but cannot successfully implement it.

After some research I noticed the [**issue**](http://code.google.com/p/flowplayer-plugins/issues/detail?id=23) had been reported earlier.